# How to get the parameters from Target in shortcut properties?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a shortcut like so:

[image]

When the C# WPF application is opened, how can I read the parameter value and set it to a property?

`C:\Users\User\Desktop\App\App.exe -p"SomeParam"`

The actual value to be extracted is within `-p""` so the value is `SomeParam`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your App.xaml.cs this function:

```cs
Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
```

and inside you can get the parameters from e, like this:

```cs
var param1 = e.Args[0]
```

in this case it would be -p"SomeParam",
so you would need to break it apart.

Comment: My Current app class looks like so: `    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            
        }
    }` Do I simply add the code like so: `        public void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            var param1 = e.Args[0];
        }`

Comment: Yes, I think it should be fine